# How to print out returned message from HttpResponse?

Tags: java, .net, android, httpresponse

I have this code on my Android phone.

```
   URI uri = new URI(url);
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

I have a asp.net webform application that has in the page load this

```
 Response.Output.Write("It worked");
```

I want to grab this Response from the HttpReponse and print it out. How do I do this?

I tried `response.getEntity().toString()` but it just seems to print out the address in memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`ResponseHandler`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java). One line of code. See [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI) and [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/15-HttpClient/Patchy/) for sample Android projects using it.

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/user");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject(responseBody);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

add combination of this post and complete HttpClient at - http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/36/

Comment: which android api version does this become available at? I might have to rewrite come code :D

Comment: I think it's been there since the beginning, or at least since Android 0.9. It's part of the standard HttpClient 4.x package.

Answer (score 12):

I would just do it the old way. It's a more bulletproof than ResponseHandler, in case you get different content types in the response.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
byte [] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

I used the following code

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   total.append(line);
}
r.close();
return total.toString();
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest approach is probably using `org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils`:

```
String message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

It reads the contents of an entity and returns it as a String. The content is converted using the character set from the entity (if any), failing that, "ISO-8859-1" is used.

If necessary, you can pass a default character set explicitly - e.g.

```
String message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(). "UTF-8");
```

It gets the entity content as a String, using the provided default character set if none is found in the entity. If the passed default character set is null, the default "ISO-8859-1" is used.

Answer (score 6):

This code will return the entire response message in **respond** as a `String`, and status code in **rsp**, as an `int`.

```
respond = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

rsp = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`
```