# entity.getContentLength() returns -1

Tags: android, android-parser, android-json, httpentity

I got `BufferedReader` object is blank, When I debug my code i found that actually the `HttpEntity` object is also seems like empty.

Here is my part of code:

// Making `HTTP` request

```
try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            long len = httpEntity.getContentLength();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
```

If i am hitting my url on the PC browser, It gives a JSON response, and also on [http://jsonlint.com/][1]

What is the exact problem, I can't understand

Comment: is this code is in asyntask or thread.?

Comment: What is the HTTP response status? Why aren't you [using a `BasicResponseHandler` to convert the response into a string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573112/139010) for you?

Comment: @wqrahd Yes, This is into the asynsTask

Comment: @MattBall Thank u very much, I have done it from BasicResponseHandler

Answer (score 0):

Check the response status and then start to read response

```
 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
 if(httpResponse .getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == SC_OK)
 {
   HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
   long len = httpEntity.getContentLength();
   is = httpEntity.getContent();
  }
```

Comment: I have got status code is 200 but still entity.getContentLength() is -1