# Error converting a String to a JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm having some issues with my android application. I currently have a String with my JSON in it.

```
 HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.brocksportfolio.com/GetPendingRequests.php");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", "Brock"));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String jsonStr = response.toString();
```

I am trying to initialize a JSONObject with that string in it like so.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

I am getting this error.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@3526f881 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I believe the reason for this error is because I am converting an HTTPPostResponse to a string and then trying to pass that string through to a JSONObject but i'm just really not sure how to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print out returned message from HttpResponse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573064/how-to-print-out-returned-message-from-httpresponse)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573112/3761545

Comment: What is the value of jsonString?

Comment: @Fahim thanks for the support but looks like the answer below worked! I added a comment of a problem that occured after fixing this problem that I ran into earlier and couldn't fix so help on that would be much appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
try {
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseBody);
```

Comment: This worked for converting! I have one more problem that just occured. I'm now getting this issue.
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"fromUser":"Andrew"},{"fromUser":"Jimmy"},{"fromUser":"Mac"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

And the line of code is this

pendingRequests = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FROMUSER);

Any ideas?

Comment: The string is an JSONArray, but you are trying to convert it to a JSONObject.

Comment: @P-aBäckström what shall I do to fix that.

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);

Comment: But now when I try to get individual ones, I get an error because the parameters or a JSONArray ask for an int, not a string... @P-aBäckström

Comment: A JSONArray is an array, so in order to get your object you can do like this: JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

Answer (score 0):

The actual message is contained by the [HttpEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) which the `BasicHttpReponse` holds. You can retrieve an InputStream from the HttpEntity, make a String out of its contents and then make a JSONObject out of it.
Of course you will need to check the response code (i.e. is it a 200?) first. All of this is quite cumbersome and error-prone.

I would recommend you to check out [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) instead, a simple JsonObjectRequest can be as easy as this (from the linked developer docs):

```
String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()     {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```